# Next.js cannot update the data using getStaticProps in Production Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

There is a problem in getStaticProps. It cannot revalidate the updated data, but it's working perfectly fine locally. However, in production on Vercel, it can't update the data. The data is coming from the MongoDB Atlas, This is how I am using this:

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const data: dataType = await getAllSchedules();
  revalidateTag("Schedule Updateddd");
  const serializedData = data.map((item: any) => {
    const { _id, ...rest } = item;
    return {
      ...rest,
      _id: _id.toString(),
    };
  });

  return {
    props: {
      serializedData,
    },
    revalidate: 20, //revalidate after 20 sec
  };
};
```

but it cant update my data

the getAllSchedules function :

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "./dbCon";

    export async function getAllSchedules() {
      const db = await connectToDatabase();
      const collection = db.collection("schedules");
      const schedules = await collection.find({}).toArray();
      return schedules;
    }
```